# Changing configurations for Jrnl

Tags: terminal, bash, permission

Greetings to the apple community.
I'm a newbie to mac and the terminal and I have no previous exposure to Linux.
I have only casually used computers. However I've been wanting to step up my game and understand a few basics.
I've installed this package http://maebert.github.io/jrnl/ which is basically to write entries on the terminal.
I've done so, and I've been following the tutorial.
However, I'm facing difficulty to edit my entries.
The documentation says that I need to change the ~/.jrnl_config file.
However, when I try to access it I get permission denied.

Harguns-MacBook-Pro-3:~ hargun3045$ ~/.jrnl_config
-bash: /Users/hargun3045/.jrnl_config: Permission denied

I have a very vague idea of user read/write permissions and about Root access, however I'm not very clear how I can go to the particular file and change settings.

Can a experienced user guide me?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're attempting to execute the `.jrnl_config` file. You don't want to execute it, you want to edit it. i.e. `nano ~/.jrnl_config` or `open ~/.jrnl_config`.

In the error message, Bash is telling you that you don't have permission to execute the file. This is because execute permission isn't given to your user (or any user, most likely) for that file. This makes sense because the file isn't meant to be executed--it's a configuration file.

Comment: Aha! Makes perfect sense. Thank you!
Any links to understanding Mr. Bash better? I'm interested in using the terminal more often.

Comment: Here's an [introduction to using a command shell](http://linuxcommand.org/lc3_learning_the_shell.php) (Bash is a command shell). The tutorial is written for Linux but most of the info will be applicable to OS X as well. Print out [this page](http://ss64.com/bash/syntax-keyboard.html) before you start. Use the keyboard shortcuts as you go through the tutorial above.